# whats the simple starter template for angularjs 1.x with webpack?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

Using vue cli I can get a simple starter template by the command

```
vue init webpack-simple
```

Do we have any similar starter template for angularjs 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of angularjs starter templates, mostly given by the community.

You can use yeoman generators for "vainilla templates"

Run from the terminal:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular
mkdir my-awesome-project-name && cd my-awesome-project-name
yo angular
```

For webpack, I found this starter template or seeder https://github.com/preboot/angularjs-webpack

You can run this:

```
git clone https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack.git my-awesome-app
cd my-awesome-app
rm -rf .git/
npm install && npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is using yeoman which is an scanfolding tool. The url is the following.

http://yeoman.io/generators/

hope it helps.